# hayman's result for $ A^2(D) $

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, conformal-geometry, quasiconformal

Consider *injective* homolomorphic functions $f:\mathbb D\to \mathbb C$ on   the unit disk $|z|\leq 1$, normalized by the conditions $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$.

Thus for $|z|\leq 1$ we have  $ f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z^k $ with $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$.
Ludwig Bieberbach conjectured in 1916 and Louis de Branges proved in 1984 that for all $k \in \mathbb N$ the inequality $|a_k|\leq k$ holds.
The Koebe function $K(z)=z/(1-z)^2$  does not belong to $ H^2(D) $ and $ A^2(D) $ . for which the extremal condition holds. Is there any analogous result for restricting the univalent functions to lie in  $ H^2(D) $.

Although the above is settled there is another result, due to Hayman and independent of De Branges' theorem, that $ \lim  a_n/n \leq 1 $ and equality holds only for Koebe function. I think it might be worthwhile to find an analogue of this in  $ A^2(D) $. In $ H^2(D) $, it doesn't make sense as $ \lim  a_n=0 $

---

[$ A^2(D)$ is the bergman space with p=2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergman_space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what "analogous" means but the estimate $|a_n|\leq n$ is best possible
when you restrict to $H^2$, and even when you restrict to polynomials. For the simple reason that the extremal function can be approximated by polynomials injective in the unit disc.

Comment: do you mean approximating by partial sums. partial sums are certainly not univalent

Comment: @Kuoshik: for each strictly smaller radius $r<1$ all Taylor's approximations $f_k$ are univalent for sufficiently large $k$. This is a direct consequence of  the Argument Principle. Now modify them as $f_{k,1}(z)=f_k((1-1/k)z)$ to get univalent approximation over the disc.